# Extracting string from filename and adding to new column in merged dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, merge

I want to import all .txt files in a directory (`ROOT.DIR`) and merge them whilst adding a new column containing the date/timestamp from the filename string. This will allow me to uniquely identify each observation.

**Sample data in .txt files with tab delimiter for MWE using macOS Monterey 12.6 and R Studio 2022.07.1 Build 554**

```
*File name*: 2022-10-17_07h50m10_AA1111_ABCD_LIBRARY_001.txt
    
    "Block" "Column"    "Row"   "F635.median"   "Median"    "B635.Median"
    
    1   1   1   6000    4000    2000
    
    1   2   1   6500    4500    2500
    
*File name*: 2022-10-17_07h55m30_AA1111_ABCD_LIBRARY_002.txt
    
    "Block" "Column"    "Row"   "F635.median"   "Median"    "B635.Median"
    
    1   1   1   8000    3500    2500
    
    1   2   1   5000    3200    1000

Ideally I would like to create a data frame that looks like

|Block|Column|Row|F635.median|Median|B635.Median|Time|
|-----|------|---|-----------|------|-----------|----|
|1|1|1|6000|4000|2000|2022-10-17_07h50m10|
|1|2|1|65000|45000|25000|2022-10-17_07h50m10|
|1|1|1|8000|3500|2500|2022-10-17_07h55m30|
|1|2|1|5000|3200|1000|2022-10-17_07h55m30|
```

```
library(tidyverse)

ROOT.DIR <- "/Users/Rob/Desktop/folder"

files <- basename(list.files(ROOT.DIR, all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".txt$"))

dates <- str_extract(files, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{2}")

merge <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(dates, \(d) {
    data = read.delim(paste0(ROOT.DIR, d, "/_AA1111_ABCD_LIBRARY_", "[0-9]{3}", ".txt"))
    data$time = d
    data
  })
)
```

This returns an error

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Rob/Desktop/folder2022-10-17_07h52m13/_AA1111_ABCD_LIBRARY_[0-9]{3}.txt': No such file or directory
Called from: file(file, "rt")
Browse[1]>
```

Creation of the `files` and `dates` objects works fine.

I think the error is in the syntax. for `data = read.delim(paste0(ROOT.DIR, d, "/_AA1111_ABCD_LIBRARY_", "[0-9]{3}", ".txt"))` within `do.call`. I've tried changing to `data = read.delim(paste0(ROOT.DIR, "/", d, "/_AA1111_ABCD_LIBRARY_", "[0-9]{3}", ".txt"))` and I still get an error.

```
Error during wrapup: unused argument (pattern = "/Users/Rob/Desktop/folder/2022-10-17_07h50m10_AA1111_ABCD_LIBRARY_001.txt")
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

I've tried to use regex to locate and import each file within the directory with a name in the format outlined at the start but I am new to regex and would appreciate any advice here.

Alternatively, perhaps I need to use `gsub` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above example I was trying to feed a regex string as a filename to `read.delim`, which it could not accept

I was able to achieve the desired output using the code below.

```
setwd("path/to/directory/contining/files") # Define the folder where the raw data files are to be read from
root.dir <- getwd() # Assign that folder as the `root.dir` object

import_and_merge <- function(root.dir){
    
  files <- fs::dir_ls(root.dir, regexp = ".txt$") # loads all the .txt files in from the `root.dir` folder
  data <- files %>%  # Create a data frame called `data`
  
  purrr::map_dfr(read_delim, .id = "Sample") %>% # imports all the files identified above into the `data` data frame and adds a column which includes the .txt filename for each row of data imported
  
  mutate(Sample = str_extract(Sample, "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{2})")) # extracts the date and time stamp from the full .txt file name row
  
  now <- parsedate::format_iso_8601(Sys.time()) #  Create object called `now`, which contains a specific date and time stamp, accurate to 1 second ins ISO8601 format

  filename <- paste0("merged-data_",now,".csv") # Define the name for the merged file to be written out

  out.dir <- "/path/to/directory/to/contain/outputs" # Define the folder where you want to merged file to be exported to. This should not be the same folder as the raw data

  write.csv(data, paste0(out.dir, filename), row.names = FALSE) # Export the merged data as a .csv file into the defined out folder.

}

### Now the function is loaded, I can run it as below ###

import_and_merge(root.dir) # Run this function with `root.dir`.
```